# Openwrt Force DNS

Tags: iptables, dns, routing, openwrt

I am working with some content filtering using openDNS. I am trying to get openwrt to redirect traffic for certain clients, based on MAC addresses, to openDNS servers.
Here is my setup:

```
openwrt gateway (chaos calmer) 192.168.1.1
client 1 00:00:00:00:00:01
client 2 00:00:00:00:00:02
Internal DNS and DHCP 192.168.1.201
```

I can set client 1 and 2 to have dhcp filters and give them openDNS, but this won't work if they change to static IPs. I can figure out a way to block them from getting into my DNS server and use external dns. I can then redirect traffic on port 53 going out to a different DNS server such as openDNS. I just am not sure how to go about doing this.

I have tried another suggestion, but I am not exactly sure how iptables works. It seems really complicated and I am trying to learn, but I am also trying to come up with a solution faster. The solutions I have tried are:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53

iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 53
```

This is supposed to set all incoming port 53 traffic to go to the router's port 53 and use their dns server which is set to openDNS, but it does not block any adult content traffic at all.

Can someone please help me?